Storage account with private access disabled. 403 when accessing blobs
I have a storage account with a private endpoint and public access disabled (the strictest version possible). The vnet is peered with a hub, in which the private dns zone, and the entry exists. I am storage blob data contributor. To complicate matters further, I use a vpn and have added the ip for the private endpoint and the url into my /etc/hostsfile.
When I want to look at a blob, I get the following error:

Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

Weirdly enough, I am able to look at secrets in a keyvault that has the same setup.
How to resolve this?

Are you trying the access the blob via URL or are you trying view the blob contents via Azure portal?

When I try to access the blob from the portal using an outside network, I receive the same issue . However, when I try to access it from a VM configured in a different network and connected via peering, it works fine. Ensure that you check the endpoint configuration and peering status. Adding a host entry is not required if you are accessing it from the portal.

@VenkatV I am trying from both the portal and the url (terraform usage). Indeed when using a vm (in the same vnet), it does work. I forgot to mention that. What specifically do you mean with checking the endpoint configuration?

May I know from where you are trying to access it? If it's working fine in the VM within the same VNet, it's expected behaviour. It should only work within the same network if the public network is disabled.

I am trying from my local machine with the url via terraform. And via the portal. Both give the same error.The request from my machine will come in via the hub, and this via the vnet link

Does your local machine have connectivity to the VNet, where the storage account has configured.

yes. We can resolve the endpoints of private keyvaults and aks clusters. Just not storage accounts

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

If you are unable to access the Blob from the VPN, there might be an issue with the DNS configuration
To verify the DNS, kindly run the command below while connected to the VPN from your local machine
nslookup <StorageAccountBlobEndPoint>

If the DNS is resolving to a public IP from your local machine, you can add the host entry as shown below
Privateendpoint IP    blobendpoint url


Once you add the host entry on your local machine, you will be able to access the blob from your local machine


Further information: I had copied the url from the private endpoint. This included .privatelink. It did resolve this address but when browsing to the blob, you use a url like above, without .privatelink. So set the config in your hosts file without the privatelink addition

I hope this helps to resolve your query? or still facing an issue?

well, Venkat, there is a weird issue with a private postgresql flexible server. I have copied the ip adress and url into my hosts file. It can ping (on a name basis), so there is connectivity. But when I try name resolution (nslookup), this fails. Any idea as to why? It is especially strange as name resolution does work for the storageacounts.
